# "header is not NLAuth scheme" but I'm trying to use OAuth in bash

Tags: bash, curl, oauth

I have the following curl command in a bash shell script. When ran, I get the error "header is not NLAuth scheme", but I'm specifically trying to use OAuth 1.0.

Code follows with omitted personal info:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://rest.na1.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=foo&deploy=bar' \
  --header 'authorization: OAuth realm=\"4478811\",oauth_consumer_key=\"foo\",oauth_token=\"bar\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"1490209398\",oauth_nonce=\"84Dg27H8Ozt\",oauth_version=\"1.0\"' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
```

The header clearly asks the curl to interpret it as OAuth. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to escape the double quotes in the header; the backslashes are incorrectly being passed as literal characters.

```
curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://rest.na1.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=foo&deploy=bar' \
  --header 'authorization: OAuth realm="4478811",oauth_consumer_key="foo",oauth_token="bar",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1490209398",oauth_nonce="84Dg27H8Ozt",oauth_version="1.0"' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
```